Asteroid--earth as a bull's eye
I'm writing a near-term SF story. An asteroid the size of Manhattan is diverted by an outside force (long story) into a collision course with earth. This body will hit in four weeks after discovery! The asteroid is nickel iron (which has dark albedo as I understand) and 20 trillion tons. It was originally a main belt asteroid diverted into the collision course. An acquaintance in a physics forum calced these figures-- diverted with an initial velocity of 37km/s into a hyperbolic orbit with a solar perigee at earth 3 months later with a speed of ~50km/s. Spotted by astronomers with a magnitude of about 12 and 1 A.U. distant, about four weeks before collision with earth.
I don't believe a heroic interplanetary mission can be mounted in time for a rendezvous, and even if it was launched, an asteroid that size cannot be diverted enough to miss our planet. Am I wrong?
EDIT: Rather than sending a manned rendezvous, maybe the US, Russia, China together could fire an extended series of rockets mounting the biggest nukes available at the rock... the sooner the better, since the earlier you hit it, the easier it is to knock off course with earth. Don't know about the US, but I read somewhere that the Russians have 20 mt warheads and China has 5 mt warheads. The US could use their multi warhead, but smaller nukes peppering the iron chunk but would that be enough? Just keep launching one rocket after another and guide them home.

As author if you want the asteroid to hit the Earth, it will hit the Earth. But if you want some reasonable answers more details are needed beyond 4Km by 20Km by ? -- which is very non-standard shape. Most importantly what is the approximate mass? General composition, and how solid would be useful to know but not as critical.

@GaultDrakkor I think the four week time limit rather rules out effective response, in the absence of secret (and probably untested) government rocketry projects. If it were four months, the size and shape and density and composition would matter a lot more, but four weeks seems pretty open-and-shut.

And if it's not, just make it a bigger rock. You are dealing with Earth-demolishing aliens, they could probably fling Mars at Earth if they had enough reason to do so. At some point Earth is gonna get creamed no matter what those puny Earthlings do.

To be fair, @SoronelHaetir - not Earth-demolishing.  The Chicxulub impactor is in the ballpark of the size of the proposed asteroid, and Earth is still here.  It wouldn't be much fun for us, but Earth would be, in a planetary sense, fine.

@Gault Drakkor The asteroid is a 20 trillion ton solid chunk of nickel iron, if that helps.

This is a question looking for a yes/no answer. It's not the best use of your or our time. If you want it to strike and destroy the planet, then perhaps you should be asking about minimum parameters to achieve this - if not then ask about feasibility of diverting it given a,b,c.

"An extended series of rockets mounting the biggest nukes available at the rock": Meteor (1979) by Ronald Neame, with Sean Connery and Natalie Wood. (And with Henry Fonda in a small role as the President of the USA.) One of the very few box-office flops in Connery's long and distinguished career.

@catsteevens while i am no astronomer keep in mind that if this asteroid could be knocked of course only a fraction of a degree it might miss earth. I mean we are talking about our planet moving 100.000 of km around the sun. And Manhattan is indeed smaller than the dinosaur killing one so averting the asteroids course might be possible within 4 weeks. Also i am very sure we could mount several space missions in a short time frame if our existence depended on it. These are just some facts i wanted to mention in the end what happens is up to you.

ICBMs are not designed to reach deep space. Their rendezvous with an asteroid will happen at best within a couple of hundred miles above the Earth surface. Certainly not enough to divert it.

Took the words right out of my mouth, user58697. An interplanetary rocket is needed.  I don't think there is anything like that, except on the drawing board. Consider the earth's gravity well, just to get a payload to low earth orbit. SpaceX's Starship could get another stage to orbit where it could fire and deliver several heavy multimegaton nukes? Needs to be launched at more than 100,000 mph, which could be possible.

@user58697 just mount warheads on Super Heavy (but there would be a limited amount of them by detection time). But yes, not "thousands" but "several" nukes would be hitting that rock before collision.

How is this asteroid aimed at Earth? If you are trying to deflect an asteroid, you can whack it and hope it ends up somewhere else. If you are aiming the asteroid, then you have to alter its trajectory to another, very particular trajectory. This implies the attachers have better tech then Earth, so they are likely to win.

Maybe, too much depends on the asteroid's actual size
Okay let's do some maths. First, if an asteroid on collision course is detected 4 weeks prior, you can only hit it with Earth-located missiles (yes not ICBMs but deep space ones) when it'll be at most two weeks away, because its speed is above our rockets' over the time before their rendezvous. In fact, we do not have rockets prepared to collide with asteroids, thus any preparation time would also take away time. So, the earliest rendezvous with a man-made rocket would only happen 1 week (603800 seconds) or less before (initial) collision.
Second, we are seeing an "asteroid the size of Manhattan" - this estimation is VERY rough, by no less than 3 orders of magnitude, as "Manhattan" might mean its skyscrapers, the size of the Manhattan island, and it does not specify the third dimension of a rock. Worse, the Manhattan Island is long and pretty narrow to be used for comparison by three dimensions, adding another order of magnitude. So, we need both a lower bound and an upper bound. With Manhattan isle being 13 km long and 2.4 km wide, and those skyscrapers being at most 600 meters tall, we are expecting to get hit by an asteroid at least 2400x2400x600m and at most of 13200x13200x13200m, with an average density of asteroids of 2.71 g/cm^3, as listed here, those example rocks would have masses of 9.4e12 kg and 6.2e15 kg respectively.
Now let's check if we can nuke the lower mass. In fact, should we have a 20 Mt nuke ready, its explosion energy is 8.4e16 J, if even a single percent would be converted into kinetic energy of the asteroid, it would accelerate by sqrt(2*8.4e14/9.4e12) ~= 13.37 m/s; over the 604800 seconds its trajectory would deviate by 8e6 meters which is more than the Earth's radius, so the answer is a definite yes; that is, if we'd hit the asteroid of that mass with our nuke and should it remain whole, it will miss Earth.
But, by comparison, this means that a single percent of energy conversion would not be enough to divert the bigger one enough to miss Earth, even the smaller asteroid would narrowly miss our planet with such a collision. But we have two aspects of nuclear strike that weren't accounted for in that simple calculation. First is relative impulse; should the asteroid approach Earth at 50 km/s, with extra 10 km/s worth of speed (Earth-related) of the rocket, we're seeing a collision speed of 60 km/s, and since the nuke's mass is measured in tons (1-10, using average of 3), its total impulse would equal 1.8e7 kg*m/s - sadly, too negligible.
But the second is ablation, vaporization and resultant jet stream of the asteroid's own debris, which is a lot harder to quantify but which might turn the 1% conversion into something seriously greater. Yet, even 100% conversion would not be enough to make a single nuke of that size cause the bigger asteroid to miss Earth. But there is another possibility - a lucky nuke blast might split the asteroid in half, giving each side the impulse "outside", giving subsequent rockets easier time to divert the halves. And finally, if one of those halves would drop into the Pacific Ocean, it would be easier to just let that one fall and concentrate on the other to make sure it would miss the planet, although it would take about 10 of the 20-Mt   warheads and the same amount of Super Heavies to reach the goal.
In total, the asteroid "the size of Manhattan", detected four weeks prior to collision with Earth, is on the brink of our abilities to be diverted to miss our planet, and only if we have a 20-Mt warhead (or several) ready to launch at any definite incoming threat.
PS: four weeks at 50 km/s is a grand total of 0.8 AU, a 10-km wide asteroid would have an absolute magnitude of 13.1 if it has albedo of 0.10, and apparent magnitude of ~14.2 at 0.8AU from Earth and 1.8AU from Sun - I say we have enough telescopes to be able to detect this asteroid from much further away, giving us more time to react and thus more chances to succeed mounting counter-asteroid armaments.

Lasers are not an option? One side hit leads to out-gassing, basically thrust vectoring..

This situation was first studied in 1967, as Project Icarus. If the OP can find a copy of the published report online, it has a lot more detail

I read a study by physicists that used 100mt nukes to divert a smaller near earth asteroid from collision. I'll try and find it but it was years ago.

@Pica no, good luck diverting a 1e15kg device with lasers that dissipate by square of distance and are unable to be focused at targets this distant. There's a fundamental issue with lasers, their beams divverge with an angle no less than lambda/D where D is initial beam diameter and lambda is wavelength. We don't have lasers with wavelengths in range of 1 nm, also we don't have lasers in space (and anyway in space we have no power to melt stuff with), so we might only add a little light to that asteroid with lasers and our current tech.

@JohnDallman Icarus is a mere 1km in diameter, also they said to use 100Mt warheads and detonate at 30m distance; also they expected a forewarning in several months. I say more than doable with current tech, also somewhat doable with tech of that day (less precise computers and clocks), and thanks for calling my attention, that was a nice theorycraft project.

@Vesper Thats why you take many, small, strong, and make a virtual hollow mirror spanning over the whole surface of the planet, focused on one point. And your asteroids need to have only a few volatiles for it to work..  and a small push at a distance is a huge course correction.

@Pica it doesn't work that way. A single 1m wide green (500nm) laser beam at 0.8AU range would become 120e9*500e-9/1 = 60000 m wide, so its power would be 60000^2 less than at muzzle. Now, should you build that "mirror" (or rather a lattice) of 60000^2 lasers that can melt rocks (IIRC 2MW/m^2 is required), this will consume 3.6 PW of power just to start, and since laser isn't quite a 100% converter, this power should be doubled. And this is about 1e5 times more than total power output of the entire planet. There are more issues, this alone is enough to debunk your idea.

This is a planet wide emergency- so power, prolonged power at that, should not be an issue: https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/ Good thing somebody ran that hypothetical..

@Pica it's already hard enough to double up power generation, your project demands 100k times that. Also that what-if ignores heat dissipation issues, extra 3.6 PW of heat is abour 2.5% total solar irradiation, so you'll overheat the planet by ~3C with it. Next. the target to light up in that what-if is Moon, a frikking thousand times closer than this one. Thus it's a MILLION times easier to light up and actually deorbit with ablation. Note that the what-if hit petawatt mark on the third last iteration, when the Moon was only lit instead of being melted. Lower that by 1M and...

@Vesper But its getting closer all the while.. and it needs just a little push

@Pica "a little push" is anyway a couple m/s delta-V, I say nuking would give that push more reliably than lasers, and by about 9 OOMs, even if ten times slower. Man, the stupid railgun, if hits, would give more delta-V to that rock than lasers! Especially since OP now states the asteroid is metallic and pretty solid.

But what if that explosion destroys and distributes the pieces, resulting in a buckshot effect?

@Pica if so, at least we tried. Also several smaller impacts have less effect on the planet core than a single large impact, resulting in less grave effects on ecology and life overall.

Not in 4 weeks
The math is pretty simple. The Asteroid will hit in 4 weeks, 2419200 seconds. Earth has a radius of approximately 6000000 meters. We wish to move the rock by 6000000 meters over 2419200 seconds.
$$v = \frac{s}{t}$$
$$v = \frac{6000000 m}{2419000 s}$$
$$v = 2,48 \frac{m}{s}$$
Obviously orbital dynamics are a bit more complicated. But the true deflection velocity will be around this ballpark. $2,48 \frac{m}{s}$ does not sound to bad, until you consider how much energy this requires.
$$F = ma$$
(We equate $v = a$, so this is the force for an instantaneous acceleration. In practice it would be spread out.)
$$F = 20000000000000000 kg \times 2,48 \frac{m}{s^2}$$
$$F = 4,96\times10^{16} N$$
$$F = 49600000000000000 N$$
Newton(meter) convert to Joule 1:1. As such, we only need a TNT equivalent of ~12 Mt. Of course, here we have to discuss a few shortcomings of this math. Namely, we are assuming all force is converted to kinetic energy. Which is not true. Cold War studies suggest ~10% of a nuclear blast on the moons surface would translate into seismic waves. But the Asteroid wobbling dosnt change its trajectory. So in practice you would need to rapidly blast the same spot. It is possible something like 90-95% of each detonations energy does not go into changing the Asteroids velocity one bit. So we are already talking about 100s of Warheads.
Another rather substantial issue with merely nuking is is that the asteroid is not a ridged body. It will compress before slowing down. Even more so since one side is going to be a lot hotter than the other. Each successive blast will do less and less work as the blasts kinetic energy gets converted into heat due to the asteroid deforming. This is why you cant nuke a rubble asteroid.
I would guess you need at least a few dozen, if not 100 ish 10 Mt nukes to do this. A lot of them will fail in flight as well, just because they are exposed to environments they were not designed for. I.e. Interplanetary space.

Hmm your asteroid is 3x heavier than my upper bound - why?

It weighs 20 Trillion tons, thats from the post. Have i misunderstood something ? @Vesper

Oh, the post was changed after my answer, adding the exact mass and composition. Sorry.

I used a Newton to megatons converter and got 5 million plus Mts.

In a comment above, that I made 2 days ago, the mass is 20 trillion tons.

@catsteevens Newton are a force. You have to convert to Joule for Energy first.

I think you are underestimating the effect that orbital mechanics has. You would only need to alter its velocity by a few meters per second(ballpark maybe 4-5) to completely miss Earth. This is much easier to accomplish in theory, although whether ICBM's can even make the trip is questionable.

@ErikHall I know that and assumed the web page owner knew that and made a conversion. A joule is not equal to a newton, but to a newton-meter, so I don't understand why it's relevant.

Here is another calculator page that comes up with the same 5,057,792 megatons, using your newton result, F=49600000000000000N, in your post above.

@catsteevens you still have to convert from Newton -> Joule and then to Mt.

You appear to be correct. We simply do not have the tech to deflect an asteroid of that size. While nukes are a popular option to do this, it's important to keep in mind that they only go suborbital. They don't have the capability(probably) to make a full orbit and definitely don't have the delta-v to escape Earth's orbit, and travel and meaningful distance to deflect the asteroid soon enough. I think in this situation, we'd just be dead.

You mistake nuclear warheads with ICBMs here. Indeed ICBMs can't leave Earth, but we have better rockets and are able to mount existing nukes to those rockets, to create IPMs, and these can reach out and hit that impending rock.

@Vesper I don't think we can procure the rockets in time to make a difference, but this is a valid point.
